# generic interface that exposes a property containing the same interface on different type

Tags: c#

I have a generic interface that needs a property (Parent) that is the same interface but on a different type. How would I go about achieving this?

```
public interface IConfigurator<T1>
{
   string TableName { get; }
   PropertyMapper<T1> PropertyMap { get; }
   IConfigurator<T2> ParentConfigurator {get;set;}   // this line is not valid c# code
}
```

I can achieve the same with the below, but I wanted to make use of c#'s properties, if applicable:

```
ITypeConfigurator<T> GetParent<T>();
void AddParent<T>(ITypeConfigurator<T> parent);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. For me the Iconfigurator interface and the last line of code works perfectly in Visual Studio, so likely i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better just to use an `object`

```
public interface IConfigurator<T>
{
     string TableName { get; }
     PropertyMapper<T> PropertyMap { get; }
     object ParentConfigurator {get;set;} 
}
```

Because if you go down this generic path too much, it will become a little messier

```
public interface IConfigurator<T,TParent>
{
     string TableName { get; }
     PropertyMapper<T> PropertyMap { get; }
     IConfigurator<TParent,??> ParentConfigurator { get; } // what are you going to put here for ?? object maybe
}
```

unless you make another interface

```
public interface IConfigurator<T>
{
     string TableName { get; }
     PropertyMapper<T> PropertyMap { get; }
}

public interface IConfigurator<T,TParent> : IConfigurator<T>
{
   IConfigurator<TParent> ParentConfigurator { get; } // what are you going to put here for ?? object maybe
}
```